# Can I make a nested list comprehension with 2 for loops and an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a nested for loop and inside the first loop, but after the second loop I have an if condition like this...

```
var1 = something
for x in range()
    for y in range()
        var2 = something
    if var1 > var2
       do something
```

Can I turn that into a list comprehension?

Comment: This code doesn't create a list.

Comment: A list comprehension can only put values into a list. If-tests can be added to exclude some values.  A list comprehension is not meant to call functions that "do something"

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the list i'm not sure, but you could do something like this:

```
something=1
var1 = something
[something for x in range(0,2) for y in range(0,2) if x>y]
```

if you can clarify if i'm close i can update my answer

Comment: 1. The question has no appends, so your answer is inaccurate. 2. Even if it was, the if is not inside the second loop, so your code wouldn't work.